# Transformation of coordinates given by a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, determine the matrix $A$ such that the map is also given by $x \mapsto  Ax $
>
> 1. $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^4  (x,y,z)  \mapsto (3x+2y-z, -x-y+z, x-z, y+z) $

How can I solve questions of this type? I'm confused by the fact that $(x,y,z)$ seemingly has three columns, while $(3x+2y-z, -x-y+z, x-z, y+z)$ has 1 row.

Also, even if they matched up (as in, the second part had 3 rows), I wouldn't know what computations to make in order to get the answer.

Comment: When you're defining a function, it doesn't matter how you write the inputs $(x,y,z)$, nor does the format of the outputs.  It matters for matrices because we need to adhere to the rules of matrix multiplication. If it helps, you can take $(x,y,z)$ to be a column vector whose entries are $x,y,$ and $z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, does
$$\begin{pmatrix}3x+2y-z\\ -x-y+z\\ x-z\\ y+z\end{pmatrix} =
x \begin{pmatrix}3\\ -1 \\1 \\0 \end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}2\\ -1 \\ 0\\ 1 \end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 1\\ -1\\ 1\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}3&2& -1\\ -1&-1&1\\ 1&0&-1\\ 0&1&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\\ z\end{pmatrix}$$
help?

Comment: It does, that looks much simpler than in my mind